# react-native value passed to component is empty

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my functional component A, I have

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
...
...
   console.debug(item);//it gives complete dictionary
   navigation.navigate("B",{item:item});
...
export default withNavigation(A);
```

In my other functional component B:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
function B({navigation}, item) {
  console.debug(item);// giving me {}
...
export default withNavigation(B);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `{ route, navigation }` as mentioned in official document. Here [official document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params).

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
function B({ route, navigation }) {
  console.debug(route.params.item);
...
export default withNavigation(B);
```

Hope it works.